# bcrypt compare is not working, login success not getting

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, bcrypt

through the sign up form I insert name , password and email in the ***DataBase*** and the password is encrypted  it is successful. but, i created a login form through that i inserted the same email and same password but *** bcrypt. compare*** is only getting login failed .

***user.js***

```
router.get('/login',(req,res)=>{            
  res.render('user/login')
});

router.get('/signup',(req,res)=>{
   res.render('user/signup')
})
router.post('/signup',(req,res)=>{
    userHelpers.doSignup(req.body).then((response)=>{
      console.log(req.body);   
   })

});
router.post('/login',(req,res)=>{
   userHelpers.doLogin(req.body)
     console.log(req.body) //.then((response)=>{   
      //    console.log(response);
      //   console.log(req.body);
      //    if(response.status){
      //       req.session.loggedIn=true 
      //       req.session.user=response.user 
      //       res.redirect('/')
      //    }else{
      //       //  req.session.loginErr="Invalid username or password"
      //       res.redirect('/login')
      //    }
      // });
}); 

// router.get('/logout',(req,res)=>{
//    req.session.destroy()
//    res.redirect('/')
// })


module.exports = router;
```

***user-helpers.js***

```
const bcrypt=require('bcrypt')


module.exports={
    doSignup:(userData)=>{
        return new Promise (async(resolve,reject)=>{
         userData.password=  salt=   await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
                  await  bcrypt.hash(userData.password,10,(err, password,hash) => {

                if(err) throw (err);
                 else
                password=hash
                  db.get().collection(collection.USER_COLLECTION).insertOne(userData).then((data)=>{

                    resolve(data.insertedId) 
                    // console.log(userData.password)
                    // console.log(userData.email)                    
                });
                });
            });
     },
        
    doLogin:(userData)=>{
         return new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{
            let loginStatus=false
            let response={}
            let user=await db.get().collection(collection.USER_COLLECTION).findOne({email:userData.email})
            if(user){  
             bcrypt.compare(userData.password,user.password).then((status)=>{
                    if(status){
                        console.log("login success");
                        // response.user=user
                        // response.status=true
                        // resolve(response)

                    }else{

                        console.log('login failed');
                        // resolve({status:false})

                    }
                })
            }else{
                console.log("login falied")
            //     resolve({status: false})
            }
        })

    }
  
}
```

i think in ***user-helper.js*** bcrypt.compare have some problem .

in my terminal only getting  ***login failed***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some mistakes in my code, I fixed it

```
var objectId=require('mongodb').ObjectId
 

module.exports={
    doSignup:(userData)=>{
        return new Promise (async(resolve,reject)=>{
        //  userData.password=  salt=   await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        userData.password=await bcrypt.hash(userData.password,10)
               
                  db.get().collection(collection.USER_COLLECTION).insertOne(userData).then((data)=>{
                    resolve(data) 
                    // console.log(userData.password)
                    // console.log(userData.email)                    
                });
                });
             
     },
        
     doLogin:(userData)=>{
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject)=> {
            let loginStatus = false
            let response = {}
            let user=await db.get().collection(collection.USER_COLLECTION).findOne({ email:userData.email })
             if (user) {
// check if password matches    
       bcrypt.compare(userData.password,user.password).then((status)=> {
                console.log(user.password)
                console.log(userData.password)
              
                    if(status){
                        console.log("login success");
                        // response.user=user
                        // response.status=true
                        // resolve(response)

                    }else{

                        console.log('login failed');
                        // resolve({status:false})

                    }
                })
            }else{
                console.log("login falied")
            //     resolve({status: false})
            }
        })

    }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [official docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt), you should use it like this,

```
    doLogin: (userData) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let loginStatus = false
        let response = {}
        let user = await db.get().collection(collection.USER_COLLECTION).findOne({ email: userData.email })
        if (user) {
            bcrypt.compare(userData.password, user.password).then((error, status) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log('login failed');
                    // resolve({status: false})
                } else {
                    if (!status) {
                        console.log('login failed');
                        // resolve({status:false})
                    } else {
                        console.log("login success");
                        // response.user=user
                        // response.status=true
                        // resolve(response)
                    }
                }
            })
        } else {
            console.log("login failed")
            //     resolve({status: false})
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: then  also showing the same . login status failed

Comment: can you check if you are getting data in "user" by logging before the compare call ? The compare block works for me.

Comment: by signup time the encrypted  password , email ,name  are  arrives at the database ***I mean in user collection *** there is no problem but compare only not working . in login time, I am typing the correct password but ***login failed***  is showing..

Comment: The bcrypt.compare block works perfectly fine for me. Why don't you try using console.log inside "if (user)" to see if "user" is set properly before checking the "if (user)" condition. Or, you could simply use a ".then()" block like you used for the "insertOne" and then place your "bcrypt.compare" block inside the ".then()" of the "findOne"

Comment: yes,  i used console.log(user.password) & (userDara.password) its showing correct   bcrypt.compare not working .